# Apply settings to all display overridden and default in views 3

Tags: views

I want to add a field to a views having around 10 displays, I want to apply it for all display but I get two option 1) this page 2) all display except override! How can apply it for all display either overridden or not?

Note, If I apply it all display it only applies to default displays and I still have to do this for overridden displays. I need a quick way to add a field to all displays whether its overridden or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Once its overridden there is nothing you can do to affect it globally.

I guess you could export the view and just add the field to the export code and then import the code.